# RxJava 2. Buffer one observables items until other observable complete

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a task to merge two observables - one is existent finite observable from database(call it **databaseStream**), and another infinite observable from queue(**queueStream**). When client subscribes, I need to subscribe immediately to **queueStream**, but buffer items until **databaseStream** will be completely finished. When that happens, I want to emit all buffered items of **queueStream**. After that all items from **queueStream** must be emit without any delay. Is there any convenient way to do it with RxJava 2?

Answer (score 0):

Found inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173252/rxjava-tricky-startwithobservable)

```
Flowable<Foo> queueStream  = queueStream()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

Flowable<Foo> databaseStream = databaseStream()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

Flowable.concatEager(Arrays.asList(databaseStream, queueStream), 2 , 1000)
    .distinct(identityFunction())
    .blockingSubscribe(System.err::println);
```